# prevent updates window from appearing in front of the other open windows

Tags: focus

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 (I can't upgrade to the next version).

How to prevent the "available updates window" from appearing in front of other opened windows?

I would like it to open minimized completely (like it does in later versions of Ubuntu). I don't want to disable the check of updates.

This behavior is very much frustrating, because it appears in front of other open windows, causing the active window to lose focus, especially when I'm typing something in it...

I need to fix this, it's **so frustrating when it changes the focus while I'm typing**!

Thanks

Comment: it appears ~once a week. Is this a problem?

Comment: @Pilot6 sure, I cannot work on a window that the updates window appear in front on it and I accindentally press Spacebar or Return then it triggers the updates window to start downloading updates... it's so annoying to give input to the new autofocused window instead of the previous correct one. I'm surprise you're asking if it's a problem, it's a shame for UX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force it to open minimized with `devilspie2` ([tutorial](https://www.linux-magazine.com/Issues/2017/205/Tutorial-Devilspie2) [repo](https://github.com/dsalt/devilspie2))

Install: `sudo apt install -y devilspie2`

Create `~/.config/devilspie2/minimize.lua`:

```
if (get_application_name() == "check-new-release-gtk") then
  minimize();
end
```

To start automatically create `~/.config/autostart/devilspie2.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=devilspie2
Exec=devilspie2
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

Reboot and it should always open minimized.

Note: this is for the upgrade to 22.04, if you meant software updates then replace `check-new-release-gtk` with `update-manager`.

Comment: it works, thanks a lot for your time. It helped me got less frustrated :-)