How to never raise a window even in focus?
Hey Everyone I would like to know how one could set a specific window to to the opposite of "always on top", basically make the window never raise even when in focus.
I'm daily driving on Ubuntu 22.04 on Gnome.
I'm using PCOIP for work and usually set it in full screen and I would love to be able to keep some of my own host PC windows to stay on top of the VM but I regularly open up windows from my host PC (web browser, zoom, text files, shells etc..). I would love to be able to keep all these windows floating on top of PCOIP at all times without having each time to set each of these windows I open up to be set to "always on top".
So basically if anyone knows of a trick which I could just set the PCOIP window to behave like to the opposite of "always on top" like setting it to "always at the back" / never raise I would greatly appreciate it.
Thanks

see here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1453091/prevent-updates-window-from-appearing-in-front-of-the-other-open-windows

Thanks this actually works wonders. Devilspie2 and setting the windows to set_window_below() does the trick.

Does it works for you with Ubuntu 22.04? With Wayland (it is used by default for Ubuntu 22.04) devilspie2 does not work...

It worked out of the box for me on Ubuntu 22.04
I checked and Wayland is enabled. I'm not using Xorg

Can you post here an answer to your own question with all the detailed steps you did to make it works? It'll be very useful!

Ok my bad I am running Xorg and not Wayland even though my config file says otherwise. Yep confirmed not working on Wayland. So Im sticking to Xorg for now
